# Could not load assembly from dynamic directory

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, shadow-copy

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly SnelStartGatewayInterface,
>   Version=12.48.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of
>   its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I got this message and found out the Assembly was loaded in the app-domain. I know the assembly must load the file for it to work properly. My project is using the shadow-copy option so i can load in assembly's while my application is running. I referenced the File/dll it asked for so it would load into the dynamic directory created by the shadow-copy option. If i place the file manually into the main folder of the dynamic directory the application wil run smoothly. but if i reference the file, the file will automatically load into:

> Dynamicdirectory/assembly/dl3/2b5603c6(random numbers and
>   letters)/SnelStartGatewayInterface.dll

This way the assembly can not load the file and crashes. Is there something i could do so it would get the file form the dynamic directory and load it properly?